# SQL - checking the date to a given time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to make a query where the records which in the create_date column[TIMESTAMP] have the previous day's date to 23:59:59 will be returned.
I don't really know how to write a where condition like this.

Simply table:

```
id [long]   create_date[timestamp]     code[varchar]
  1         2021-06-11 11:00:55.716    simplycode1 
  2         2021-06-28 23:32:07.115    simplycode2
  3         2021-06-29 20:00:00.631    simplycode3
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: `SELECT FROM  some_table WHERE create_date BETWEEN current_date - '1 day' AND current_date;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use date comparisons:

```
where create_date >= current_date - interval '1 day' and
      create_date < current_date
```